# VirtualBox Ubuntu internet connection problem on Chrome ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, google-chrome

I am a beginner Ubuntu user, I use it via VirtualBox.

I was eligible to connect internet yesterday, but today I can't access most of the sites. For example I can search something in Google, but I can't connect to yahoo.com. I can access to amazon.com, but I can't go to Amazon EC2.

I am open to any advices, thanks for your help in advance.